# Block execution program until callback function complete execution

Tags: c++, qt

How to block program execution until callback function complete execution ?

From my main() i launch  interface.getImage(); function who want to get images from our database. When we receive images the callback function void InterfaceColliseo::dataReceived (std::shared_ptr data) start to execute.
But I have a problem my program main() terminate before my callback function execution ?

**main.cpp**

```
int main(){
        InterfaceColliseo interface;
        IMAGE = true;
        interface.getImage();

        // want to block program here
        return 0;
}
```

**callback function**

```
void InterfaceColliseo::dataReceived (std::shared_ptr<IData> data)
{
    if (!data->isValid())
        return;

    const unsigned char* twoDImageData = data->get2DImageData();
    int width2DImageData = data->getWidth2DImageData();
    int height2DImageData = data->getHeight2DImageData();
    const unsigned char* disparityData = data->getDisparityData();
    int widthDisparityData = data->getWidthDisparityData();
    int heightDisparityData = data->getHeightDisparityData();

    if(IMAGE) {
        saveImage(twoDImageData, width2DImageData, height2DImageData,
                  disparityData, widthDisparityData, heightDisparityData);
        IMAGE = false;
    }

    if(ACQUISATION){
        QList<GstObservationBasic> detectorData = data->getObstaclesData();
        getObstacles(detectorData);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just can use thread from std. When you use join, the main thread will wait until joined thread will finish his job.

```
#include <thread>

//in main
std::thread myThread(interface.getImage);
myThread.join();
```

Comment: This won't help, `myThread` will finish its job just after the call of `interface.getImage()`, which is not blocking.

Comment: @Annyo Ok, you probably have right! I don't know what method getImage implementation is and how (and where) dataReceived will be called

Comment: @Raffallo I like to block execution until callback finish not the interface.getImage() function.
I use condition_variable
extern std::mutex mtx;
extern std::condition_variable cv;

Comment: dataReceived is a callback function which be called after recovery images from database.

Comment: @Kamel-GH can you give us code of InterfaceColliseo?

Comment: @Raffallo I add my InterfaceColliseo.h and InterfaceColliseo.cpp

Comment: @Kamel-GH Ok, now I see better solutions for your problem. Just can you tell me what do you want to use it? It should be run all the time and listening for new images, or just wait for a single image and then make some stuff?

Comment: @Raffallo it should be run N times (N is a giving integer) and listening for new images.
The problem: in the first time N=0, my program can't wait images received (from callback dataReceived)

Comment: @Kamel-GH You will need to change your InterfaceColliseo. Now when you use getImage method, you just enable waiting on new image. 
Unfortunately, waiting for pictures is probably done on separate threads, which is why the main thread goes so far as to be able to continue to do your own thing, or end the program. You have to rebuild your program to create a class / method waiting for all the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "interface_colliseo.h"

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;


bool IMAGE;
bool ACQUISATION;

InterfaceColliseo::InterfaceColliseo(){
}

void InterfaceColliseo::startStreaming(){
    dataReceiver = _device->getDataReceiver();
    start();

}

void InterfaceColliseo::getImage(){
    dataReceiver = _device->getDataReceiver();
    start();
}

InterfaceColliseo::InterfaceColliseo(QString IP): _IP(IP) {
    qDebug() << "INDUS-5: IP server: " << _IP;
    qDebug() << "INDUS-5: Connecting to sensor...";
    _colliseoClient.setIPServer(_IP);

}

bool InterfaceColliseo::connect2UT(){
    QString path = qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/Configuration.ini";
    QSettings config(path, QSettings::IniFormat);
    _IP = config.value("Connection/IP","10.0.3.144").toString();

    _colliseoClient.setIPServer(_IP);
    _device = _colliseoClient.getDevice();
    _device->connectSensor();
    bool connect = _device->isConnected();
    return connect;
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::sensorName(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getOrderNumber();
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::sensorFirmwareVersion(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
           ->getDeviceInformation()->getFirmwareVersion();
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getSensorHeadPN(QString sensor){
     return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
             ->getDeviceInformation()->getSensorHeadPN(sensor);
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEvaluationUnitSN(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEvaluationUnitSN();
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEvaluationUnitPN(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEvaluationUnitPN();
}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEvaluationUnitFirmwareVersion(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEvaluationUnitFirmwareVersion();

}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEstimatedAngleX(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEstimatedAngleX();

}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEstimatedAngleZ(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEstimatedAngleZ();

}

QString InterfaceColliseo::getEstimatedHeight(){
    return _device->getDeviceDiagnostics()->getOperatingData()
            ->getDeviceInformation()->getEstimatedHeight();

}

void InterfaceColliseo::saveImage(const unsigned char*twoDImageData,
                                  int width2DImageData, int height2DImageData,
                                  const unsigned char*disparityData,
                                  int widthDisparityData, int disptHeight){
    Configuration configuration;

    QString logFolder = configuration.getLogFolder();

    QImage imgRight(twoDImageData, width2DImageData, height2DImageData, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QImage imgDisparity(disparityData, widthDisparityData, disptHeight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

    QPixmap imgRght = QPixmap::fromImage(imgRight);
    QPixmap imgDisp = QPixmap::fromImage(imgDisparity);

    QString rghtImgPath = logFolder + "raw_image.png";
    QString dispImgPath = logFolder + "disp_image.png";

    imgRght.save(rghtImgPath, "PNG");
    imgDisp.save(dispImgPath, "PNG");

}


void InterfaceColliseo::getObstacles(QList<GstObservationBasic> detectorData){

    if (detectorData.size() == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "Obstacles: no detected obstacles.";
        return;
    }

    Configuration config;
    config.writeLog("***************Obstacles List Acquisation******************");
    Q_FOREACH(const GstObservationBasic &obs, detectorData)
    {

        qDebug() << "Obstacles: " << gstObservationToString(obs);
        config.writeLog(gstObservationToString(obs));
    }
}


void InterfaceColliseo::dataReceived (std::shared_ptr<IData> data)
{
    if (!data->isValid())
        return;

    const unsigned char* twoDImageData = data->get2DImageData();
    int width2DImageData = data->getWidth2DImageData();
    int height2DImageData = data->getHeight2DImageData();
    const unsigned char* disparityData = data->getDisparityData();
    int widthDisparityData = data->getWidthDisparityData();
    int heightDisparityData = data->getHeightDisparityData();

    if(IMAGE) {
        saveImage(twoDImageData, width2DImageData, height2DImageData,
                  disparityData, widthDisparityData, heightDisparityData);
        IMAGE = false;
    }

    if(ACQUISATION){
        QList<GstObservationBasic> detectorData = data->getObstaclesData();
        getObstacles(detectorData);
        ACQUISATION = false;

    }

}

void InterfaceColliseo::start() {

    dataReceiver->addListener(this);

    if(dataReceiver->isListening())
        dataReceiver->stopListening();

    dataReceiver->startListening();
    _device->triggerSingleImageAcquisition();
}
```

Comment: If this code presents a self-answer, please, provide some text with explanations. If this is additional exposed code for your question, please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55900726/edit) the question. For me, it seems this is far too much code to serve as a [mcve]. It's surely possible to reduce it to the absolutely necessary minimum to reproduce your issue and this might help to raise more attention to your question.